# Magento 2 notify shopper when reach $x to spend $y to get Z item for free

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2, coupon-codes, promotional-banner

Is there any extension out there about a promo rule that if they reach $90 in their basket notify with a pop up or place banner etc... that if they spend $100 they'll get X item for free etc...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but i would suggest this extension for your request:

> https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-sales-pop/

You can see the Guide before purchasing it

> https://docs.mageplaza.com/sales-pop/index.html?_ga=2.253094221.596292686.1581089043-951433032.1580293637

Also you can chat with their support for further questions .

I use some of extension of Mageplaza and they do good coding.

Comment: Definitely  worth investigating thx for the suggestion!